# AD: Lookup NT-style name using distinguishedname

Tags: active-directory, ldap

From the commandline,how can I look up an NT-style name using a distinguished name?  That is, I want to put in "CN=Alice Smith,OU=Head Office,DC=Cyberdyne,DC=local" and get out "CYBERDYNE\ASmith"

Edit: Active Directory level 2003, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the sAMAccountname ??

try the following...

**dsquery * "CN=Alice Smith,OU=Head Office,DC=Cyberdyne,DC=local" -scope base -attr sAMAccountName**

Although that does not get the DOMAIN\ prefix (CYBERDYNE)

*Note: I think dsquery is installed on DC's only, you may have to grab a copy from a DC if you want to run it elsewhere...*

.. Ken

Comment: Thanks, this gives the account name and I can derive the domain name from the Distinguishedname. (I can't see how to get the NT-style domain name programatically, but I'm only dealing with half a dozen domains here so I can just do that bit by hand)

Answer (score 4):

I missed getting to your question early enough, perhaps, to save you any of that "by hand" labor you mentioned in your comment to Ken Hughes. To do this programmatically you're looking at using the [iADsNameTranslate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706046(VS.85).aspx) interface. You can get a lot of mileage out of it for dealing translating the various possible names of an AD account (GUID, SID, samAccountName, displayName, DN, etc).

Example:

```
Option Explicit

' Constants for the iADsNameTranslate object. (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772267(VS.85).aspx)
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4 = 3
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779 = 1

Const ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC = 3

Dim objNameTranslate 
Dim strUsersamAccountName

' Create a nametranslate object and init to talk to a global catalog server
Set objNameTranslate = CreateObject("NameTranslate")
objNameTranslate.Init ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC, ""

' We're looking for a distinguished name, aka 1779
objNameTranslate.Set ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779, "CN=Bob, OU=blah, ..."

' Translate into the user's samAccountName
strUsersamAccountName = objNameTranslate.Get(ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4)

WScript.Echo strUsersamAccountName
```